# Ошибка десериализации Protocol Buffer (Steamworks, CS:GO)

Tags: c#, google-protobuf, steam

Приветствую.

Имеется вот такой код:

```
[ProtoContract(Name = "CMsgClientMMSLobbyChatMsg")]
public class CMsgClientMMSLobbyChatMsg : IExtensible
{
    public CMsgClientMMSLobbyChatMsg();

    [DefaultValue(0)]
    [ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = false, Name = "app_id", DataFormat = DataFormat.TwosComplement)]
    public uint app_id { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(null)]
    [ProtoMember(4, IsRequired = false, Name = "lobby_message", DataFormat = DataFormat.Default)]
    public byte[] lobby_message { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    [ProtoMember(2, IsRequired = false, Name = "steam_id_lobby", DataFormat = DataFormat.FixedSize)]
    public ulong steam_id_lobby { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    [ProtoMember(3, IsRequired = false, Name = "steam_id_sender", DataFormat = DataFormat.FixedSize)]
    public ulong steam_id_sender { get; set; }
}
```

Вот так я пытаюсь получить информацию о сообщении:

```
private void LobbyChatMessage(LobbyChatMsg_t r)
{
    var pvData = new byte[4096];
    CSteamID sender;
    EChatEntryType eType;

    SteamMatchmaking.GetLobbyChatEntry(
        (CSteamID) r.m_ulSteamIDLobby,
        (int) r.m_iChatID,
        out sender,
        pvData,
        4096,
        out eType);

    CMsgClientMMSLobbyChatMsg msg;

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(pvData, 0, 4096))
    {
        msg = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<CMsgClientMMSLobbyChatMsg>(stream);
    }

    log($"Got lobby message. \nMessage: {msg.lobby_message}\nSender: {msg.steam_id_sender}");
}
```

Вот такую ошибку получаю каждый раз:

```
Вызвано исключение: "ProtoBuf.ProtoException" в protobuf-net.dll
Invalid field in source data: 0
```

Массив pvData не пустой, проверял. Содержит в себе сообщение.
Где ошибка?

Comment: `MemoryStream`, вероятно, содержит в конце неиспользуемые байты. Возможно, проблема именно в этом. Попробуйте обрезать эти байты перед десериализацией.

Comment: Она содержит их и с самого начала, два или три символа \0 в ряд и между параметрами разделение при помощи \0\1 идет. Сейчас попробую обрезать их в конце.

Comment: Не получается их обрезать. Может есть какое другое решение?